# should i use getcwd(-1) or getcwd(-1, -1) in neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim

related to this vi.stackexchange post [How do you go back to your to global current directory after inheriting an lcd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15052/36876)

what should i use in my neovim? @mass @elliottcable

Comment: Have you read the help?

Comment: yes, i have but didn't understand a thing

Comment: Hm, indeed, the documentation is not very clear on how to return the global directory: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/eval.txt#L4513-L4524  I would suggest opening an issue at the neovim repository asking for a doc update to make this clear, how to get the global current directory.